# How to define "-" as a word character in minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer

I have a specific problem that when I run "grep", my default grep command contains the `-i` option, and sometimes I wish to repeat the last search but case-sensitive.  So I press `M-p` (previous command),

```
grep <some-options> -i lastSearchWord
```

then a number of `M-b` (backward-word) to get to the `-i` option, but this puts me between "-" and "i": so then I have to switch to `C-b M-d` to delete the option.  And it's annoying to switch from Meta to Control here (and the need for this extra command at all): it would be more helpful to get the cursor to before the "-".

I know it's possible to redefine the categorization of characters per mode, but I am out of touch with Emacs terminology so don't know what to search for.  How do I redefine "-" to be a "word character" in the Minibuffer only?

Comment: If you use `lgrep` you can just customize option `grep-template` to be what you want, i.e., to not include `-i`.

Comment: The question title seems to be off-target, and you can probably come up with better tags...

Comment: The original question's title is `How to define "-" as a word character in minibuffer?` You cannot get better than that, and I hate it when people who think they're doing something for the improvement actually make stuff worse.  Such a waste.

Comment: I rolled back @ideasman42's edit.

Comment: The reason to make this question more general is the delimiter character isn't important, someone else may ask **"How to define "." as a word character in minibuffer in macOS?"**  and **"How to define "?" as a word character in minibuffer for the German language?"** - there is no need to be spesific about which delimiter exactly you want to change. That you want to change a delimiter is enough information.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, `backward-kill-sexp` (which I have on <kbd>C-M-backspace</kbd>) is the thing to execute after `backward-word`. That eliminates both the "i" and its preceding "-".

If you need to do this often, you might consider writing your own command:

```
(defun my-case-insensitive-grep ()
  "Call `grep' without the "-i" switch."
  (interactive)
  (grep (s-replace " -i " " " (grep-default-command))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Emacs 28.1, this can be done much like any other mode using a mode hook & `modify-syntax-entry`.

```el
(add-hook 'minibuffer-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    ;; Treat '-' as a word.
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- "w")))
```

Comment: Does `minibuffer-mode-hook` really exist? Seems to not be defined for me (26.1)

Comment: Yes, it does in emacs 29 (and probably in 28 as well: I haven't checked). It does not exist in 27.2 AFAICT and presumably not in anything earlier either.

Comment: It went in to 28.1 with this commit: "commit 55db25b2579e5d84dfcf3a15957fc7a827abf25f
Author: Alan Mackenzie <acm@muc.de>
Date:   Tue Apr 20 10:14:40 2021 +0000

    Introduce and use minibuffer-mode.  This fixes bug #47150
...`

Comment: This is a future answer, presumably. Neither Emacs 28 nor Emacs 29 have been released. The latest release is 27.2.

Comment: Emacs 28.1 has now been released.